# Preventing url.el from asking for a user name and password

Tags: emacs, httprequest, http-authentication

Is there a way to override its default behavior of prompting for a user name and password when it encounters the HTTP status code 401? Some option or hook perhaps?  I want to prevent it from prompting for a user name and password.  I want it to immediately return with HTTP status code at 401.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you want it to do instead?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: What code/command are you using to send the GET request?